# Order of nodes with networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout

Tags: python, networking, graph, nomachine-nx

I'm relatively new to python coding, and I am using the following code to produce a graph, with 40 nodes, and the layout of the nodes is given using this code:

```
 pos = nx.circular_layout(graph_anchor, **kwargs)
```

The following code creates graph_anchor:

```
    graph_anchor = convert_ebunch_to_graph(ebunch_anchor)

def convert_ebunch_to_graph(ebunch):
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    g.add_weighted_edges_from(ebunch)
```

My question is, how do I work out in what order the nodes are being graphed i.e. how do I work out how this code decides which nodes to put beside each other and what order to lay them out in?

Answer (score 1):

From the source of [nx.circular_layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/drawing/layout.html#circular_layout):

> ```
> def circular_layout(G, dim=2, scale=1, center=None):
>     # dim=2 only
>     """Position nodes on a circle.
>
>     Parameters
>     ----------
>     G : NetworkX graph or list of nodes
>
>     dim : int
>        Dimension of layout, currently only dim=2 is supported
>
>     scale : float
>         Scale factor for positions
>
>     center : array-like or None
>        Coordinate pair around which to center the layout.
>
>     Returns
>     -------
>     dict :
>        A dictionary of positions keyed by node
>
>     Examples
>     --------
>     >>> G=nx.path_graph(4)
>     >>> pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
>
>     Notes
>     ------
>     This algorithm currently only works in two dimensions and does not
>     try to minimize edge crossings.
>
>     """
>     import numpy as np
>
>     G, center = process_params(G, center, dim)
>
>     if len(G) == 0:
>         pos = {}
>     elif len(G) == 1:
>         pos = {G.nodes()[0]: center}
>     else:
>         # Discard the extra angle since it matches 0 radians.
>         theta = np.linspace(0, 1, len(G) + 1)[:-1] * 2 * np.pi
>         theta = theta.astype(np.float32)
>         pos = np.column_stack([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])
>         pos = _rescale_layout(pos, scale=scale) + center
>         pos = dict(zip(G, pos))
>
>     return pos
> ```

It seems that positions are generated by dividing 360 degrees by the number of nodes. 
which node ends up where is decided by this line:

> ```
>         pos = dict(zip(G, pos))
> ```

zip(G, pos) iterates through the nodes of the graph in order. and assigns positions to them. If you want to change the position, you need to change the order.

Example:

```
# make dummy graph
G = nx.from_numpy_array(np.random.rand(12,12)>0.5)

# test order of nodes:
for node in G.nodes:
    print(node)

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
```

[image]

Here, the first position that is assigned is that of node 0, then we go counterclockwise.

I could not find an easy way to change the order of the nodes in G, so here is a little workaround which creates a new graph with randomised order:

```
nodes = list(G.nodes(data=True))
edges = list(G.edges(data=True))
np.random.shuffle(nodes)

H=nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(nodes)
H.add_edges_from(edges)

pos = nx.circular_layout(H)
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos=pos)
```

[image]

So changing the order of the nodes inside the graph changes where they will end up in the circular layout.

Comment: So the dictionary containing the node determines the structure?

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered, so I don't think so. Nodes are stored in G.nodes(), which returins a nodeview object. In any case, if you add nodes from a list, the order of that list seems to be preserved.